# How to view error message or code when a pptx file can't be opened by MS Office and needs repair

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, apache-poi, powerpoint, openoffice.org

I am programmatically generating a open office (.pptx) document using apache poi. When I try to open the document using MS office, it gives off a message "Powerpoint found a problem with content in file xyz.pptx" and asks me to repair the file. After the office suite repairs, the document just opens fine. I am able to open the document in Libre Office and OpenOffice and the contents of the zip folder (contents of pptx) seems to be fine.

Is there a way to display the actual error message or reason as to why Office was not able to open the document in the first place and needed repair? Is there any api or jar for validating such documents before opening them in Office suite. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's any way of getting PPT to tell you what it didn't like about the file, but since it's able to repair it, it's likely something fairly small.  After it's repaired the file, save it to a new name, then run a file compare on the various files within the zips, your version vs repaired version.  That might help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Wish there was an OpenXML validator for such issues.

Comment: Such as [this one](http://ooxmlvalidator.codeplex.com/)?